# javascript readout position of object AND show by onclick, or save in variables

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am trying to read out the x and y position of an object. Ideally, there would be an "onclick" button that can be clicked and then the position would be read out and displayed.

Here is the code and here the website: https://www.unisg.bplaced.net/JS/dragdrop3.html

The things that I wanted to do is

- read out the position and save them in variables
- even showing them within an alertbox would be great. But, I would need to save them ultimately in my survey program.

Here is the code of the site so far

```html
<html><head>
    <style>

    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/park2.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
    }


    #dragMe {
      width: 100px;
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/silhoutte3.png');
      background-size: 100px 300px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
    }
    
    #dropMe {
        width: 12em;
        height: 12em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="dragMe" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; ">
<p>You</p>
</div>

<div id="dropMe"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#dragMe').draggable(
    {
        containment: $('body'),
        drag: function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
            var xPos = position.left;
            var yPos = position.top;
            $('#positionX').text('positionX: ' + xPos);
            $('#positionY').text('positionY: ' + yPos);
        },
         accept: '#dragMe',
        over : function(){
            $(this).animate({'border-width' : '5px',
                             'border-color' : '#0f0'
                            }, 500);
            $('#dragThis').draggable('option','containment',$(this));
        }
    
    });

function myFunction1() {
    alert("The position is" + position.left);
}

    </script>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Click me</button>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify one of the attribute for the `dragMe` id because you have specified both the positions as absolute in the css above and relative in the inline css of the element.

And to get the position in `px` add the code as

```
<html><head>
    <style>

    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/park2.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 7px;
      touch-action: none;
    }


    #dragMe {
      width: 100px;
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url('http://www.unisg.bplaced.net/silhoutte3.png');
      background-size: 100px 300px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
    }

    #dropMe {
        width: 12em;
        height: 12em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="dragMe" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; ">
<p>You</p>
</div>

<div id="dropMe"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#dragMe').draggable(
    {
        containment: $('body'),
        drag: function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
            var xPos = position.left;
            var yPos = position.top;
            $('#positionX').text('positionX: ' + xPos);
            $('#positionY').text('positionY: ' + yPos);
        },
         accept: '#dragMe',
        over : function(){
            $(this).animate({'border-width' : '5px',
                             'border-color' : '#0f0'
                            }, 500);
            $('#dragThis').draggable('option','containment',$(this));
        }

    });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("#dragMe").position();
    alert("Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left);
  });
});

    </script>

<button>Click me</button>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body></html>
```

Here the jQuery code will get you the positions required.

Comment: Kunal, works perfectly! Perhaps one follow-up question: if I want to write the values in a variable into a form, let's say "v_1" and "v_2", is it right to do      document.getElementById("v_1").value = document.$("#dragMe").position().xtop;

Comment: So, the variables v_1 and v_2 exist on the site, and I would like to also save the variables.

Comment: after defining   `var x = $("#dragMe").position();`  you don't need to define the `id` to all the variables you can just do it in a short way as `var v_1 = x.top` and `var v_2 = x.left`.